# ffmpeg4android & MediaRecorder: Forcefully cutting video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android-mediarecorder

Using MediaRecorder to record video from SurfaceView

#### Recorder

```
recorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get( CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P );
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setCamera( camera );
recorder.setAudioSource( MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT );
recorder.setVideoSource( MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT );
recorder.setOutputFormat( recorderProfile.fileFormat );
recorder.setAudioEncoder( recorderProfile.audioCodec );
recorder.setVideoEncoder( recorderProfile.videoCodec );
recorder.setOutputFile( tempFile.getPath() );
recorder.setOrientationHint( 270 );
recorder.setVideoFrameRate( recorderProfile.videoFrameRate );
recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate( recorderProfile.videoBitRate );
recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate( recorderProfile.audioBitRate );
recorder.setAudioChannels( recorderProfile.audioChannels );
recorder.setAudioSamplingRate( recorderProfile.audioSampleRate );
recorder.setVideoSize( size.width, size.height );
```

#### Commands

> "ffmpeg"
> "-y"
> "-i"
> file
> "-strict", "experimental"
> "-vf", "[in] crop=480:640 [out]", 
> "-s", "640x480", 
> file

*The videosize is 480x640 because its rotated before cropping*

**It cuts video to 500 milliseconds of length.**

## Why?

Comment: does the desktop version do this as well?

Comment: I have not tried desktop. I have no access to do this on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

**recorderProfile.videoCodec:** vp8 cuts the end for me, but not vp9.

Keep in mind I'm working with the web MediaRecorder() on Chrome Android.

Its also tied to audio, recording a audio track with the video stream does not trim the end with vp8 on mobile or desktop.

This does not happen with vp8 on desktop.